# phonegap android ajax requests work for GET but not POST

Tags: android, ajax, post, cordova

Sending the below request in my phonegapp-ed android app works for GET but not POST. 
With GET, everything works. With POST, the request goes through but the POST variables 
are not coming through on the server side, and the server returns a 
json response that says 'no parameters supplied.'

POST works fine from our mobile app - it is just the phonegap app where we are having an issue.  What am i missing here???  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

I've tried changing the settings on the $.ajax call, the android manifest, everything I can think of.

Also, i'm using Android 2.2 and Phonegap 1.0

---

```
function goTeam(){ 
    var dataString={lat:currentLocation.lat(),lng:currentLocation.lng()}; // this all works 
    $.ajax({ 
            url: 'http://example.com/request/goTeam', 
            data: dataString, 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: 
                    function(b) { 
                            if(b.status==1){  // woo hoo! it works 
                            } else { 
                                    // the request went through but something was wrong - this is what i'm getting with POST 
                            } 
                    }, 
            type: 'post',  // works with GET, doesn't work with POST 
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert("Noooo."); } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap does work with both GET and POST - cross-domain security issues do not apply.  We had an idiosyncratic error our code that was preventing it from working.  Phonegap is pretty awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying cross-domain requests? Only GET requests work this way. You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for this kind of request, but only GET works.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me because it works on iOS and phonegap says this: 
Q. I want to create an application for phonegap to access externally deployed web services via AJAX. How can i resolve the issue with the
cross-domain security policy of XmlHttpRequest?
A. The cross-domain security policy does not affect PhoneGap applications. Since the html files are called by webkit with the file:// protocol, the security policy does not apply.
(in Android,you may grant android.permission.INTERNET to your app by edit the AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: quick update: the ajax requests are NOT working in iOS. I guess my fundamental question is if you can use do an external POST ajax request in phonegap... phonegap documentation and sites like this lead me to believe I can: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/jquery_ajax_post?utm_content=reply_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification#reply_6897716   but my own efforts lead me to believe the opposite! others must've faced this issue before...

Comment: @Florian Thanks for replying my question. I am voting for you.