# calling Struts action Using phoneGap

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, struts

i m new to phonegap, can please anyone tell me what will be the jquery.ajax/jquery.post call structure for getting the data from action class? or in other words what i have to give in URL attribute of call? to call action of server from mobile page?

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ to know how to make ajax calls using jquery.

In general URL would be < action name >.do (.action depends on struts config property) unless you are trying to access cross domain site.

Parameters are specified in data field.

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: i think u misunderstood my question. i am asking about accessing remote server. when my app is on iphone how can i invoke action of my existing web app on server? for that call what i have to do? <action name>.do is fine for local host. but when i only have HTML5 pages on mobile then what type of call i have to send on server

Comment: Then, you would definitely need to provide complete URL. Please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762621/phonegap-android-ajax-requests-work-for-get-but-not-post He has used full URL in his/her example

Comment: thanx. one more thing i want to ask, if my url is http://example.com/request and my action is abcAction and its mapping is /abc then wat will be my call? will it be like this? url:http://example.com/request/abc    ????

Comment: It should be 'http://example.com/request/abc.do' In general, all .do/.action will be forwarded to struts controller. Otherwise server might assume there are other services exist and look in web.xml

Comment: Thanks, i will try it on phoneGap and will let you know